# How to create some white space between material icon and description?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, google-material-icons

I have this design here:

[image]

You can see the material icon is a bit too close to the description. I thought I could create some padding between both by doing something like this:

```
.location-secondary-info span:first-child {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

That has been ineffectual.

This is the component code:

```
renderLocation() {
    const filteredLocations = this.props.locations.filter(location => {
      return !location.name.match(/[A-Z0-9]+$/);
    });

    return filteredLocations.map(location => {
      if (location.airport_code) {
        return (
          <div key={location.id}>
            <div className="location">
              <h1>
                {location.name} ({location.airport_code})
              </h1>
              <div className="location-secondary-info">
                <span>
                  <i className="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>
                  {location.description}
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div key={location.id}>
            <div className="location">
              <h1>{location.name}</h1>
              <div className="location-secondary-info">
                <span>
                  <i className="material-icons">location_city</i>
                  {location.description}
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select the `i` element inside the span, so:

```
.location-secondary-info span i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

With `span:first-child` you were selecting the first `span` element inside `.location-secondary`.